# how to continue debug when a crash happened in xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, crash

My code crashed, and the following line gets highlighted in red. But some crash handle function should continue. How can i debug this crash handle function:

`NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler(&HandleException);`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The error that you're generating doesn't result in an Objective-C exception, so exception handlers aren't going to be invoked for it.

If you're trying to test exception handling, you should replace your method code with a `throw`.  If you're trying to test for handling of that specific code, you should create a signal handler for the error that's cut off by your screen shot.  (SIGABRT, SIGSEGV, ...?)